# How to register user on MongooseIM server using .Net service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, xmpp, xmppframework, mongoose-im

I am trying to implement the a .Net Web mechanism that will hold user profile and other activities.

On success the user will be able to chat hence have to be registered under MongooseIM server with JID creation.

This have to be done by the Asp .Net server to generate a JID for the user and execute the action similar to `$sudo bin/mongooseimctl register username hostname password.`

The similar activity will be done in case the Remove account is called to by user and Asp .Net will talk to MIM to execute the `$sudo bin/mongooseimctl unregister username hostname` command.

Do we have any way to achieve this by following ways.

1) Curl command we tried but its in PHP , but need more guidance how to do this.
2) Is MongooseIM having any facility to expose outside any web service to execute the mongooseimctl commands.

Appreciate for any leads given.

Answer (score 0):

> 2) Is MongooseIM having any facility to expose outside any web service to execute the mongooseimctl commands.

Yes, it has. Since version 2.0.0beta2 we provide a REST API for backend services. More info about it can be found in our documentation:

1. http://mongooseim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/http-api/http-administration-api-documentation/
2. http://mongooseim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/swagger/index.html

Comment: You are super fast Michal I will try this with team and reply.

Comment: We unable to get response on hitting this request, do we need to add any module or configuration for this.